# Number of columns does not correspond to the number of rows in the header in row(s) Magento 2

Tags: magento2, import

I am trying to upload products in **Magento 2.2.6** from default import using CSV. I am getting this error while checking data on CSV.
[image]

I have double check my CSV file has accurate columns and values in it.

Comment: Check the specifiew row, that have not all the values.

Comment: I have checked they have same and correct values

Comment: Check Visibility column, it must have "Catalog, Search" as value. Probably this may create issue for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error comes in case of some of data are available in row, but column name is not available in first row of your csv. If it looks ok then might be csv break because of your some data has ,.

I suggest that upload csv in google sheet and export as csv then try to import.

Please let me know still if you are getting error.

Comment: yeah i have data in values having " , "

Comment: shall i remove " , " from values ?

Comment: No, do not delete. First try to upload your csv into google sheet and then download as csv. Do not open that csv in your pc. Just import that downloaded file. Please let me is this working for you?

Comment: the issue is " , " you were right (Y)